# VS Code SQL Developer Plugin showing wrong values for NUMBER(19,0) columns

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code

executing the same query against the same database resulting in different outputs in VS Code SQL Developer Plugin and the standalone SQL Developer.

VS Code SQL Developer Plugin:

[image]

Standalone SQL Developer:

[image]

The standalone SQL Developer output is correct. It seems a issue with displaying values in VS Code.

Any idea if there´s an option in VS Code to correct that?

Comment: File a bug with the extension.

Comment: If you open the JS Console of your browser and put `6124897014919821795` in there, it will give you `6124897014919821000`. VS Code is written in JavaScript/TypeScript, and "common" numbers in these languages are using IEEE 754 64-bit double precision floating point representation, where the largest "precise" integer value is `9007199254740991` (if you're already in the JS Console, you can get it via typing `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`). There's a `BigInt` type in JS, with arbitrary precision, but the extension would have to be modified explicitly in order to make use of it.

Comment: ... so there can't be a simple setting lying around somewhere that could adjust this behaviour.

Comment: [That extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.sql-developer) is seemingly developed by Oracle Corporation. The creators of the Oracle DBMS should know that `NUMBER` columns don't necessarily fit in integer types in most programming languages, so it doesn't seem they put too much resources in this project. On the other side, version `23.4.0` released two months ago is tagged as "initial release" (?) so perhaps you're beta-testing some new product that's still not mature enough :)

Comment: it's more complicated than 'just use BigInt' and we have many resources on this project - but it is logged as a Sev2 bug and we are going to fix it

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the VS Code SQL Developer Plugin. See comments for details.

I tried to file a bug here: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/vs-code-sql-developer-plugin-showing-wrong-values-for-numbe-0291

Comment: It's a bug, you're not doing anything wrong, and there's no 'setting' to fix it - other than using TO_CHAR on your query if you know in advance it'll overlfow the INT precision.